# Empty plot with ggplot + ggridges + gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm getting an animation with empty canvas when using `ggridges`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(gganimate)

df = data.frame(id = rep(1:5, each = 10),
                t = rep(1:10, 5),
                y = runif(50))

p1 = ggplot(df,
            aes(x = t,
                y = id,
                group = id,
                height = y)) +
  ggridges::geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity",
                                fill = NA) +
  gganimate::transition_reveal(t)

gganimate::animate(p1, nframes = 50, fps = 10)
```

A static plot, not an animation, displays properly.

Comment: can you try  `gganimate::transition_manual(t, cumulative = TRUE)`

Comment: @Roman It works but the animation isn't smooth. Only 10 frames are rendered regardless of the `nframes` parameter.

Comment: Of course. Since your `t` has only 10 values.

Comment: With `transition_reveal(t)` I get a nice smooth appearance of time series. It just doesn't seem to like `ggridges`.

Comment: transform your `t` to date?